# NGINX streaming RTMP: no accepted connections, no errors

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, streaming, rtmp, obs

I'm trying to send video stream from OBS studio over RTMP to nginx server on a VPS
Problem: nginx doesnt seem to be accepting input on the URL, OBS times out on send

I've followed this tutorial on making sure that nginx has everything it needs: https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-rtmp-on-ubuntu-14-04#Configuring_Software_to_Work_with_Nginx_RTMP

I've got nginx 1.17.9 on a VCS (Ubuntu) running the default config file with the following RTMP addition:

```
rtmp {
    server {
            listen 1935;
            chunk_size 4096;

            application live {
                    live on;
                    record off;
                allow publish all;
        }
        application hlslive {  #rtmp push stream request path 
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/;
            hls_fragment 3s;
            hls_playlist_length 18s;
        }

    }
}
```

I've tried having OBS stream to either  `rtmp://IP:1935/hlslive` or `rtmp://IP:1935/live` - I get an error message saying the attempt timed out. I am able to access http://IP/ just fine. I can test the config file and it passes. Any suggestions about how to troubleshoot?

UFW status is disabled, OBS can stream to other servers.

Answer (score 0):

```
rtmp://IP:1935/hlslive
```

This is the path of the application, not for the stream.

For example: `rtmp://IP:1935/hlslive/teststream`

With this example URL, you will have teststream under hlslive application. Same pattern goes for other applications too.

Syntax is pretty basic

```
rtmp://nginxip:port/application/streamname
```